# How can photons/particles/objects/things be massless?

Tags: photons, mass

How could we say a photon be massless? A thing which has no mass is seem to be just like it does not exist or we say it is nothing. It should be very less but we can't say "massless".
Everything which exist should have mass (quantity) that's why it is existing. According to me there is nothing such thing called massless! Every particle is actually a matter! because if anything have should also have volume and according to the definition of matter: anything which has mass and occupies space is called matter?

Answer (score 4):

> How can photons/particles/objects/things be massless?

Photons aren't massless the way people think. A photon has a non-zero "inertial mass" and a non-zero "active gravitational mass". But it doesn't have a "rest mass" because it's never at rest. You can't slow down a photon like you can slow down an electron. Or speed it up by pushing it. Rest mass does not apply to a photon. And nowadays when people say mass without qualification, they mean rest mass.

> How could we say a photon be massless? A thing which has no mass is seem to be just like it does not exist or we say it is nothing. It should be very less but we can't say "massless". Everything which exist should have mass (quantity) that's why it is existing.

You are confusing rest mass and energy. If a thing has no energy it doesn't exist. But if it has no rest mass because it's moving at c rather than sitting there at rest, it still exists. Light exists, you can see because of it, grass grows because of it, lambs eat grass, and you eat lambs. You are here because of this light. It exists, and so do you. In fact, we make matter out of light in pair production.

> According to me there is nothing such thing called massless! Every particle is actually a matter! because if anything have should also have volume and according to the definition of matter: anything which has mass and occupies space is called matter?

There's light, and there's matter. We convert one into the other in pair production or in annihilation. An atom bomb converts a small percentage of matter into gamma radiation, which is light. A fire converts an even smaller percentage of matter into light.